# Error while trying to scale up App Service Plan scale up and correct app service plan SKU for VNET integration

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans, azure-webapps

I would like to use VNET integration for my Web App. My Web App is talking to Azure SQL DB at the moment and i am going to use Private Link for Azure SQL. So for that it is essential to enable VNET integration for my web app as per the URL :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

I am currently on Standard S1 SKU. I would like to know will my SKU support VNET integration or i have to upgrade my Web App to premium?
In the link that i have pasted it says :

"The VNet Integration features:

Require a Standard, Premium, PremiumV2, PremiumV3, or Elastic Premium pricing plan.
Support TCP and UDP.
Work with Azure App Service apps and function apps."

So whatever SKU i am on, is it supported for VNET integration?
Also, when i try to scale up to Premium P2v2 i get the message that "Premium V2 is not supported for this scale unit".

Please help

Comment: Standard support VNET Integration - did you try to enable VNET Integration with your current plan and it failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all S1 is the minimum SKU that supports VNet integration.

However, your issue arises due to how hardware is arranged in Azure data centers.  These are composed of "scale units", don't know the actual hardware size, but these have specific capabilities.

As newer hardware becomes available, new scale units and SKUs are introduced, but the older scale units usually do not support the new capabilities, and typically it's not economic to upgrade them to do so.

So in your scenario, you deployed into a scale unit that supported S1 but not the newer SKUs.

The way around this is to do an initial deployment to the larger size e.g. PremiumV3 and then lower the size to S1 - that way you are on hardware that is capable of the newer SKUs.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I just read that [older Standard App Services do not support VNET Integration](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/56945) - only newer ones **built** on Standard or Premium V2 do. Which means even upgrading from an old Standard S1 might cause an issue - likely what you're seeing.

> The feature is available from all App Service scale units in Premium
> V2 and Premium V3. It's also available in Standard but only from newer
> App Service scale units. If you are on an older scale unit, you can
> only use the feature from a Premium V2 App Service plan. If you want
> to make sure you can use the feature in a Standard App Service plan,
> create your app in a Premium V3 App Service plan. Those plans are only
> supported on our newest scale units. You can scale down if you desire
> after that.

See below for more information. Copied from the Github issue for easier reference.

> If your app runs in an App Service deployment where PremiumV2 isn't
> available, or if your app runs in a region that currently does not
> support PremiumV2, you will need to re-deploy your app to take
> advantage of PremiumV2. You have two options:
>
> Create a new resource group, and then create a new app and App Service
> plan in the new resource group, choosing your desired Azure region
> during the creation process. You must select the PremiumV2 plan at the
> time the new app service plan is created. This ensures the combination
> of resource group, App Service plan, and Azure region will result in
> the App Service plan being created in an App Service deployment that
> supports PremiumV2. Then redeploy your application code into the newly
> created app and app service plan. If desired you can subsequently
> scale the App Service plan down from PremiumV2 to save costs, and you
> will still be able to successfully scale back up again in the future
> using PremiumV2.
>
> If your app already runs in an existing Premium tier, then you can
> clone your app with all app settings, connection strings, and
> deployment configuration into a new app service plan that uses
> PremiumV2. In the Clone app page, you can create an App Service plan
> using PremiumV2 in the region you want, and specify the app settings
> and configuration that you want to clone.

Also this from the same Microsoft Documentation says:

> The feature is available from all App Service scale units in Premium
> V2 and Premium V3. It's also available in Standard but only from newer
> App Service scale units. If you are on an older scale unit, you can
> only use the feature from a Premium V2 App Service plan. If you want
> to make sure you can use the feature in a Standard App Service plan,
> create your app in a Premium V3 App Service plan. Those plans are only
> supported on our newest scale units. You can scale down if you desire
> after that.

Also more information about [incompatible Resource Group and App Service SKU combination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/app-service-configure-premium-tier#scale-up-from-an-unsupported-resource-group-and-region-combination). You will note that this documentation has already changed it to Premium v3

---

Original Answer

So [Microsoft clearly says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) that a Standard plan falls in scope for VNET Integration support. And as you rightly pointed out:

> The VNet Integration features:
>
> Require a Standard, Premium, PremiumV2, PremiumV3, or Elastic Premium
> pricing plan.

You do not need to upgrade to another plan.

Comment: Ok i also though the same when i saw this issue https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/56945

Comment: I updated my answer - it seems far more complex than I thought. I couldn't replicate it on my end most likely cause our App Services were recently deployed. I've also added those points from the issue in my answer just for easier reference. I will give it a try again and let you know.

Comment: Microsoft didn't change their documentation even after the Github Issue was raised. People are getting confused here

Comment: Yes I think the problem is that Microsoft should update it to reflect that older Standard SKUs do not support it. But newer ones do. How old is your App Service? I just tried to replicate it on my end. I found an old Standard App Service that didn't support VNET Integration, I cloned it and then upgraded the clone to P1V2 - Success! Was also able to integrate to VNET. Can you give that a try? If it works I'll update my answer

Comment: I tried a couple of other scenarios and I noticed that Standard App services in some regions do not face this limitation.  There really is no pattern. I would suggest you try 1. Clone to a new ASP in premium v2 and see if it integrates 2. Once integration done, try to downgrade back to standard S1.

Comment: I think your best bet is probably to deploy a new ASP in a new RG entirely. That could place your new ASP on a newer server farm. Cloning still seems to put it back on the same farm which causes the issue. Or maybe consider cloning to a new ASP and then try moving the ASP to a new RG - Sorry I know I'm giving you so many things to try but I'm feel the frustration with this thing right now! It's really frustrating!

Comment: Yes i somehow managed to upgrade my Dev subscription to P2v2 from Standard S1. But i don't see the option to integrate with my VNET after i upgraded. I don't see the option to upgrade to P2v2 for my other subscriptions, QA, STG and PROD. I raised a ticket with Microsoft. Microsoft is telling Hardware might not be available and asking me to clone my app and upgrade the SKU like you suggested. My App Service Plan is like 6 months old now. The problem is i have many things associated with these apps. So changing and redeploying is a big issue now at this moment.

Comment: All my App Service Plans are in Central US. So i was able to upgrade successfully my DEV app, but not the other environments even though they are in the same region. Also after upgrading the DEV app to P2v2, i don't see the option to do VNET integration